# Rotating a sprite in a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graphics

I have several sprites in one image and I want to draw individual sprites to a canvas. I am having trouble getting them to rotate.

When I attempt to rotate a sprite, it seems that it never rotates around the point that it should be.

I'm using the following function. The angle is set at loading time.

```
Sprite.prototype.draw = function (ctx, x ,y) {
    if (this.angle == 0) {
        ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height, x, y, this.width, this.height);
    }
    else {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(x, y);
        ctx.rotate(this.angle * this._TORADIANS);
        ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height, x, y, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.restore();
    }
}
```

I've looked through several tutorials and nothing seems to work in this case.

Comment: Is the issue that it's rotating around the top left point rather than around the center of the image? If you can post a simplified JSFiddle of what you're doing that would help. Otherwise try adding `ctx.translate(this.img.width/2,this.img.height/2);` before the `rotate` then `ctx.translate(-this.img.width/2,-this.img.height/2);` after the `rotate`, does that solve your issue?

Comment: @Jared Simply yes, and no. I would have to draw the image correctly too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start by translating the context to `x, y` plus half the dimensions of the image so that the context origin is at the center of the image's desired location:

```
ctx.translate(x + this.width / 2, y + this.height / 2);
```

Rotate the context by the desired number of degrees:

```
ctx.rotate(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);
```

Draw the image, offset by half its dimensions to account for the position of the origin:

```
ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height,
                        -this.width / 2, -this.height / 2, this.width, this.height);
```

Now undo the rotation and translation:

```
ctx.rotate(-this.angle * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.translate(-x - this.width / 2, -y - this.height / 2);
```

In your case, you can change `Sprite.draw()` as follows.

```
Sprite.prototype.draw = function (ctx, x, y) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x + this.width / 2, y + this.height / 2);
    ctx.rotate(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height,
                            -this.width / 2, -this.height / 2, this.width, this.height);
    ctx.restore();
};
```

The following snippet demonstrates this approach in general.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var width = 600,
      height = 600,
      canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0],
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a';
  function draw(x, y, degrees) {
    context.translate(x + image.width / 2, y + image.height / 2);
    context.rotate(degrees * Math.PI / 180);
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height,
        -image.width / 2, -image.height / 2, image.width, image.height);
    context.rotate(-degrees * Math.PI / 180);
    context.translate(-x - image.width / 2, -y - image.height / 2);
  }
  image.onload = function () {
    var degrees = 0;
    function loop() {
      degrees = (degrees + 1) % 360;
      context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      draw(0, 0, degrees);
      window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    };
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  };
};
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: I really do appreciate your in depth answer! After thinking about it, it makes a little more sense to me. Move the point of origin to the X and Y location of the object being drawn, and then draw it. I think that is what confused be at the glace of people's code. Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 4):

If you are rotating around x,y then your code should look like this:

```
ctx.translate(x, y);
ctx.rotate(this.angle * this._TORADIANS);
ctx.translate(-x, -y); // this part is missed in your case
ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height, x, y, this.width, this.height);
```

Comment: I don't really understand how your code works when the only difference is the second translate. But then again, I can see how it would. I do mean that you would need to refocus where the point of origin is (0, 0), but for it to be negative of the image's X and Y locations? That kinda throws me off. But isn't that what `ctx.save();` and `ctx.restore()` is for? But thank you. +1

Comment: this is the only anwer that worked for me amongs many others found over the internet, thank you!